# Angular - Add component B inside component A

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I have the following structure in my project,

```
src
- component-a
-- component-a.component.ts
-- component-a.html
-- component-a.scss
-- component-a.component.spec.ts

- component-b
-- component-b.component.ts
-- component-b.html
-- component-b.scss
-- component-b.component.spec.ts

- app.component.ts
- app.module.ts
- app.html
```

I'm using **component-a** inside my app.component.ts, so I have included it in declarations in the app.module.ts.

```
declarations: [
        App, ComponentA,
    ],
```

And in the app.html: `<component-a></component-a>`

Now I want to add **component-b** inside my **component-a**.
So whatever I tried, when I use `<component-b></component-b>` inside **component-a.html** I get this error:

```
Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
'component-b' is not a known element:
1. If 'component-b' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'component-b' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("
      [ERROR ->]<component-b></component-b>
"): ng:///AppModule/ComponentA.html@7:6 ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value:
```

How do use component-b in component-a.html?

- I tried importing component-b in component-a.component.ts
- I tried importing and adding component-b in the app.module.ts
  declarations.

Comment: You have to create separate module for component A (ng g module componnent-a), move there component-a and component-b and then import that module inside main module (app.module).

Comment: Try this [fix](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40145633/angular2-unhandled-promise-rejection-template-parse-errors) , this may solve your problem

Comment: Try this [fix](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40145633/angular2-unhandled-promise-rejection-template-parse-errors) , this may solve your problem

Comment: You can use [entryComponents](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39756192/what-is-entrycomponents-in-angular-ngmodule).

Comment: Why don't you just add `ComponentB` to `declarations` of `app.module` just like you did with `ComponentA` ?

Comment: @echonax Hi. I tried that. error is still there.

Comment: @user3607282 Seems to be working here: http://plnkr.co/edit/H929znCRMcqlwuI4ySvp?p=preview

Comment: @echonax I'm in rc1. I believe the current version is rc2? Could that be a reason?

Comment: @user3607282 do you use angular 4 or 2?

Comment: @echonax angular 2. sorry i'm still learning all of these. :(

Comment: @user3607282 no problem, I'm just trying to figure out the issue. If you have an `@NgModule`, you are at least using version rc.5. Do you have an `@NgModule`?

Comment: @echonax yeah i do.

Comment: @user3607282 can you include the full app.module (`@NgModule` part)?

Comment: @echonax Ok. I'm very confused now. It's working when I declare it in the app.module like you said. It didn't work before. Can you add it as an answer so I can mark it. Thanks for all your replies. I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As we've discussed in the comment section. You can provide `ComponentB` inside your `app.module` to import it throughout your app.

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';

@NgModule({
  ...
  declarations: [
    AComponent, BComponent
  ]
})    
export class AppModule {}
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/H929znCRMcqlwuI4ySvp?p=preview

Comment: This is the bad way of doing it though.. :|

Comment: @Chrillewoodz why?

Comment: In real applications you build with modules, and then lazy load the modules with the declarations also inside the modules. Although this works it'll get out of hand quick in a bigger app.

Comment: @Chrillewoodz the question does not state that this is a big app. This could be a 2 component app. Would you still create 2 modules for it? Of course I know what you mean and appreciate the comment but saying that it is **the** bad way is a bit premature at this point. And as you know: _Premature optimization is the root of all evil_ -- DonaldKnuth

Comment: It could, but most likely isn't unless it's a hobby project. I just dislike when examples show you **a** way of doing it, but not necessarily the one that you should or would use in a real example. Then you're more likely to always use that solution because "that's how I learned to do it in the first place". Your answer works but mine is more complete. So I guess our answers complements each other's.

Comment: @Chrillewoodz I fully support you idealist thoughts but I disagree on the idea of giving a "professional" answer. I'm sure you didn't learn lazy loading from a SO answer, at least the core concept of it. And it's hard for a starter to jump start with the module/lazy-loading concepts without knowing the core concepts. If you bring up these kind of contexts then it becomes more complex for a starter. Your answer is a bit complex for a starter and as OP mentioned in the comments it couldn't handle the task. There might be lots of reasons for that as we know only the part of the architecture.

Comment: @Chrillewoodz In my opinion answers that are complex may discourage a starter from learning angular because things are not happening soon. But if they see the "Hello World" in the html, I'm sure they will dig deeper into the documentation.

Comment: Yeah I agree. I don't usually take the person's individual skill into account when posting answers, perhaps I should take your advice and start doing that.

Comment: @Chrillewoodz And I will keep in mind to give more real-life suitable answers :-)

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a module for both components.
2. Import `component B` into `component A`'s module `imports`.
3. Done.

Example (A Module)

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';

import {BModule} from '@components/b/b.module';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BModule
  ],
  exports: [
    AComponent
  ],
  declarations: [
    AComponent
  ]
})

export class AModule {}
```

Example (B Module):

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';

@NgModule({
  exports: [
    BComponent
  ],
  declarations: [
    BComponent
  ]
})

export class BModule {}
```

Comment: Hi. I followed these steps and the error still shows. do you have any idea why that might be? :(

Comment: Is there anything I have to do inside b.module?

Comment: You have to export the component and declare it. Like in the example above. I'll add it to the answer.

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that both modules should be importing a shared module where common modules, pipes and directives are declared. You can read about the shared module in angular's official styleguide.